# How to post multiple NSNotification?

Tags: swift, nsnotification

I currently use postNotification multiple times with NSTimer, but the observer is receiving it only once.

What's the way to receive the same notification multiple times without adding multiple observers?

My timer is created like this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And inside the update method is:

```
let testNotification: NSNotification = NSNotification(name: "testNotification", object: self, userInfo: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(testNotification)
```

This is how I register the observer in one of the viewcontrollers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testNot), name: "testNotification", object: nil)
    updateView()
}
```

I add the observers in a viewcontroller as one normally would.

I can confirm the timer works, because update() is being called at the regular interval, and the observer does receive the notification for the first time, but it does not recur.

Please let me know if you need to see more of the code.

Comment: You need to show us the code that creates the timer and the code that posts the notification.

Comment: And the code that registers for the notification.

Comment: Where did you put the method to unresgister your view controller? Maybe is inside viewDidDisappear or testNot

Comment: I did not have one. I tried to remove and re-add the observer in testNot(), but that didn't work, either.

Comment: Is this all happening within one class or two distinct classes?

Comment: Timer and update methods are in one class, and the observer adding and removing are naturally in a viewcontroller class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your situation, but if is a screen for example and this screen is deallocated or dismiss and you don't set to remove all observers, most like is that is generating multiple observers for the same name, looks you receive the first one, after, another is allocated and you don't receive because they lost reference. That should help

Comment: I want to receive multiple notifications, but I only add the observer once. In other words, I want to use the same notification set on a timer for recurring notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating new object of NSNotification.

Answer (score 0):

So, my testNot() function presented a modal view, and that somehow disabled further notifications from posting. Now I have to figure out how I can present a view and still keep receiving notifications. Alert views still work correctly. It throws an error in the debug console about the alert view still present when further notifications are received, but once the alert view is dismissed, everything goes back to normal.